# from django_extensions.db import UUIDField ImportError: cannot import name UUIDField

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to fix a problnme regarding  UUIDField. While running myb ./manage.py it shows up it cannot import UUIDField
this is the model i'm using.

from django.db import models

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings
from django_extensions.db import UUIDField
from django_extensions.db.fields import UUIDField

class Text_Message(models.Model):
     send_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
     delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
     uuid = uuidfield.fields.UUIDField(auto=True,
    help_text=_('Used for associating replies.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `UUIDField` has been removed from [django-extensions 1.8](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#180). Django has included a [`UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) since Django 1.8, so you don't need to use an external package anymore.

If you are using an older version of Django, you would have to install an earlier version of django-extensions to get the UUID field. However, note that Django 1.7 and older are unsupported and do not receive security updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```